# How to PUT multiple resources via a REST API

Tags: json, api, rest, http

I am trying to figure out the best way of adding multiple users to a group via a REST API.

Right now, I am thinking this is the best way of adding a single user at a time:

`PUT /groups/123/{userID}`

Then, to remove the user from the group:

`DELETE /groups/123/{userID}`

But how would I add multiple users to the group at the same time? Would this be the best way?

`PUT /groups/123`

Content body as an array:

```
[
  "user1",
  "user2",
  "user3"
]
```

...and to remove the users from the group, I would do the same thing via a `DELETE` request.

Is there anything "wrong" with this setup, or would there be a better, more "industry standard" way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

> How to PUT multiple resources via a REST API

You don't do that - each request in HTTP has one-and-exactly-one target [resource](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1); the semantics of the [PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) request are that the message body of the request is a replacement representation for the resource.

---

Resources are generalizations of *documents*.

It's entirely reasonable to have a document that is a representation of the members of some group.

```
PUT /groups/123

[
  "user1",
  "user2",
  "user3"
]
```

What this request *means* is "replace your copy of /groups/123 with this copy".  It's purely a document editing command.

The useful work - like actually making changes to the master group membership list, is a *side effect* of making your copy of the document look like the provided copy.  See [Webber 2011](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m08s).

In this style, "removing" a user from the group would look like another edit to the /groups/123 document

```
PUT /groups/123

[
  "user1",
  "user3"
]
```

Of course, remote authoring semantics aren't required; you could instead do:

```
POST /groups/123

Please remove user1
```

or

```
POST /groups/123

action=addUser&id=user4
```

---

> to remove the users from the group, I would do the same thing via a DELETE request

Careful - [DELETE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5) (like PUT) means something specific in HTTP, and that may not be what you mean.

> Relatively few resources allow the DELETE method

The semantics of DELETE belong firmly in the [transfer documents over a network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m08s) domain, not in the "manage users and groups" domain.